# Making a responsive HTML design "UNRESPONSIVE"

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have an HTML document, and it is responsive.

I want to make it unresponsive. How can I do this in the most efficient, and quickest way?

I have tried giving `min-width` to `html` and `body`; however some objects are still responsive to the window size.

Comment: You need to give an example of what you're working with, and some decent research efforts. Have you tried to go through the entire code and edit CSS settings to make it un-responsive?

Comment: You have to remove all media queries and add a container div after <body> section adding a min-size to it.

Comment: Kindly ask all of your users to use an identical device ;)

Answer (score 8):

- remove any `<meta name="viewport ..."` tags in the head of your pages
- remove any `@media (..) { ... }` blocks
  in your css file
- in the css that remains, you may need to actually set a fixed page width, eg

  body{
  width = 960px;
  }

Depending on the specifics of your site there may still be other fixes needed, but this will get you started.

Comment: Also all dimensional parameters in the css should be specified with measument unit. E.g. you can't mix px with in or cm. I think you can't use vw, vh, rem, em also

Answer (score -2):

Your question is not fully clear, you want to disable css or funchtionlity.

If you want to disable Full HTML Page including all the elements you can use HTML DOM Property.

```
HTMLElementObject.disabled=true
```